# Obtener los valores de cada celda de una tabla HTML con String.Split en vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, regex

Información previa: Estoy realizando una aplicación en la que copio parte del código de una página web (de una tabla de ésta para ser exactos) con el objetivo de meter la información de ésta en una base de datos. Para ello había pensado en dividir la cadena que el usuario pega en un `textbox` en un `array` para después ir metiendo los datos con un bucle. El caso es que no soy capaz de encontrar la expresión regular que me "elimine" todo aquello que está entre `<>` para dividirlo.

Os pongo un ejemplo de la cadena que introduciría el usuario:

`<tbody><tr id="timetableBlocks-23-01-18" style="display: block;"><td style="width: 135px;">23/01/2018</td><td style="width: 135px;">759.655</td><td style="width: 135px;">46.705</td><td style="width: 135px;">42.724</td><td style="width: 135px;">224.863</td><td style="width: 135px;">76.364</td><td style="width: 135px;">171.784</td><td style="width: 135px;">0</td><td style="width: 135px;">197.215</td></tr><tr id="timetableBlocks-22-01-18" style="display: block;"><td style="width: 135px;">22/01/2018</td><td style="width: 135px;">553.995</td><td style="width: 135px;">42.573</td><td style="width: 135px;">194.736</td><td style="width: 135px;">26.671</td><td style="width: 135px;">221.950</td><td style="width: 135px;">13.780</td><td style="width: 135px;">0</td><td style="width: 135px;">54.285</td></tr></tbody>`

Entonces el objetivo sería, por así decirlo, eliminar las etiquetas html y quedarme solo con lo que estas encierran. El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
Dim DatosBruto As String = TextBox1.Text

    If DatosBruto Like "<tbody>*</tbody>" Then
        Label7.Text = "ha introducido bien los datos"

        Dim pattern As String = "(<*>)" //<-- aquí es donde no funciona
        Dim DatosPartido() As String = Regex.Split(DatosBruto, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        Label1.Text = DatosPartido(1)
        Label2.Text = DatosPartido(2)
        Label3.Text = DatosPartido(3)
        Label4.Text = DatosPartido(4)
        Label5.Text = DatosPartido(5)
        Label6.Text = DatosPartido(6)
```

La expresión regular que está puesta está porque ha sido la ultima que he probado, pero vamos que obviamente no funciona, ¿se os ocurre como podría ser?

Actualmente los datos que me saca no tienen sentido (vaya, que separa por donde le da la gana), de momento los estoy poniendo en `label` hasta que consiga que sea lo que quiero. El objetivo sería que sacara algo así como

```
label1 = 23/01/2018, 
label2 = 759.655, 
label3 = 46.705, 
label4 = 42.724, 
label5 = 224.863, 
label6 = 76.364
...
```

Comment: Hola Charlie. Puedes mostrar el resultado que actualmente consigues y el que realmente quieres conseguir? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: la verdad es que sacar el resultado que consigo ahora no tiene mucho sentido porque son partes mezcladas, el qué busco conseguir creí que quedaba claro pero lo añado por si acaso. gracias por la información

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solución con regex (no recomendada)

Una forma sencilla es buscar que coincida con:

- cualquier cantidad de espacios en blanco: `\s*`
- el caracter que abre el tag: `<`
- cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean un `>`: `[^>]*`
- el caracter que cierra el tag: `>`

y esto repetido 1 o más veces, por lo que va dentro de un grupo: `(?:`…`)+`

Es decir, el regex que coincide con uno o más tags consecutivos sería:

```
(?:\s*<[^>]*>)+
```

Esto obviamente te generaría elementos vacíos al inicio y al final del array que deberías filtrar luego.

**No obstante**, regex no es la herramienta para analizar HTML. Hay millones de casos en los que fallaría. Incluso con un regex gigantesco, siempre se puede encontrar una excepción en la sintaxis de HTML que haría que falle. Para solucionarlo correctamente, deberías usar [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (*Document Object Model*).

- ¿qué pasaría si hay un `">"` dentro de un atributo de una etiqueta?
- ¿qué pasa si hay `<!-- comentarios -->` dentro del HTML?
- ¿Y si hay que validar un CDATA?
- ¿Estás seguro de que tu HTML no puede ser un poco más complejo de lo que esperabas?

Hay varias opciones. Por ejemplo, una opción muy utilizada es con HTML Agility Pack.

---

#### Con DOM (usando [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/))

Es mucho más sencillo cuando se usa una herramienta pensada para eso. La idea es que de esta forma estamos analizando la sintaxis de HTML correctamente: seleccionando cada nodo del HTML como un objeto.

Primero, declaramos lo básico:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
```

```
Dim DatosBruto As String = "<tbody><tr id=""timetableBlocks-23-01-18"" style=""display: block;""><td style=""width: 135px;"">23/01/2018</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">759.655</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">46.705</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">42.724</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">224.863</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">76.364</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">171.784</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">0</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">197.215</td></tr><tr id=""timetableBlocks-22-01-18"" style=""display: block;""><td style=""width: 135px;"">22/01/2018</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">553.995</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">42.573</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">194.736</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">26.671</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">221.950</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">13.780</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">0</td><td style=""width: 135px;"">54.285</td></tr></tbody>"
```

Y ahora sí, la idea es generar el DOM (un objeto `HtmlDocument`), al que le cargamos la estructura analizada del string con [LoadHtml()](http://html-agility-pack.net/from-string).

Luego, usamos el selector XPath `//tbody/tr/td` (*tag `tbody` en cualquier lugar del documento, adentro un hijo directo `tr`, y adentro un hijo directo `td`*) pasándolo a [SelectNodes()](http://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes), que nos devuelve una colección que podemos recorrer y obtener el valor de cada celda.

**Código**

```
'generamos el DOM
Dim html = New HtmlDocument()
html.LoadHtml(DatosBruto) 'pasando tu string con el HTML

For Each cell In html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr/td")  'XPath para seleccionar cada celda
    'imprimir en consola el texto de cada celda
    'esto lo adaptarías a donde quieras mostrar el resultado
    Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText)
Next
```

**Resultado**

```
23/01/2018
759.655
46.705
42.724
224.863
76.364
171.784
0
197.215
22/01/2018
553.995
42.573
194.736
26.671
221.950
13.780
0
54.285
```

**Demo**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXcOFv